# Cant execute bat file via Jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

The following bat file is working when running this directly on the machine.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Starting the Application ...
START "app" java -jar app-0.0.1.jar
```

When calling this file via Jenkins it's not working.

[image]

Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: Is that supposed to have the `call` keyword in it?

Comment: I don't think but I was trying different options

Comment: Try without the `call` keyword. If that doesn't work, replace `call` with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ` (with a space after `/c`).

Comment: Which suggestion worked, specifically? (For the benefit of others)

Comment: The last one (AKA via CMD.EXE)